# Axios POST doesn't send data (object)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, axios

I'm trying to send the following object from my REACT app to my node.js express server via axios.post:

```
const customerData = {
  firstName: enteredFirstName,
  lastName: enteredLastName,
  address: enteredAddress,
  phone: enteredPhone,
  ccn: enteredCCN,
  username: enteredUsername,
  password: enteredPassword,
  email: enteredEmail,
  role: "customer",
};
```

This is my code which i use to send the object:

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8080/customers/", customerData)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The request is sent, but the data object isn't recieved by the server (but the request is), and if i use JSON.stringify on my object, it does deliver it, only as a string, which isn't what i want (CORS are open).

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, when you observe the failing request, what does it contain in terms of parameters/body?

Comment: "*it does deliver it, only as a string, which isn't what i want*", but that's how it works. You have to stringify your data before sending on the client side and parse it back to JSON on the server side. But typically if you pass an object as second argument to `axios.post` axios does the necessary conversions automatically (you still have to handle it correctly on the server side ...) So I'd say, your problem is currently at the server, where you don't have an appropriate middleware to parse your request body back to JSON

Comment: Can you put a debug point on beginning of the Node JS API endpoint and check whether you hit that endpoint when you send the request?

Comment: You can check in the browser's network tab to see if the data is present in your request. If not, it's the problem of the client site. Otherwise, you probably miss the middleware to parse JSON data on the server.

Comment: Đăng Khoa Đinh, i believe you are correct, since upon further inspection the middleware app.use(json()) wasn't properly implemented, causing the whole ordeal. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can check in the browser's network tab to see if the data is present in your request. If not, it's the problem of the client site. Otherwise, you probably miss the middleware to parse JSON data on the server. –
> Đăng Khoa Đinh

this was correct - use(json()) wasn't implemented correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure after sending object that there is some values in it
2. Check if you dont have any typo
3. Sometimes problem can be using slash '/' after the end
   try without slash

   .post("http://localhost:8080/customers", customerData)
4. Check your logs in console
5. Try using other clients to send data for example REST Client in vscode

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client

Comment: That's why it's so weird...even without the / at the end, it's still delivered as { } though in the console i see the payload.......

Comment: Also, why is the info being sent only when i stringify it? did I miss some configuration?

Comment: Try to send message with only properties / fields  for example 
.post("http://localhost:8080/customers/", { firstName: enteredFirstName, lastName: enteredLastName, ...})